# Is the sum of an invertible symmetric matrix with the identity invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am doing a computation with matrices where I have a symmetric matrix $B$ which is invertible. An expression of the form $Id + B$ comes up. Is this matrix invertible? I think it is but can't come up with a way to prove it.

Comment: $-I+I$ is not invertible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether $B$ is symmetric or not is irrelevant. $I+B$ is invertible if and only if $-1$ is not an eigenvalue of $B$.

If $B$ is positive semidefinite, then $I+B$ is invertible, because $-1$ cannot possibly be an eigenvalue of $B$. Alternatively, if $(I+B)x=0$, then $0=x^\ast(I+B)x=\|x\|^2+x^\ast Bx\ge\|x\|^2\ge0$. Therefore $x$ must be zero and $I+B$ is invertible.

Comment: Duh, thanks for taking me out of my stupidity! In fact in my computations I also know that $B$ is positive definite.